# Why the Java lib stream() creates an array of objects when the element streamed is a splited string?

Tags: java

I have a string as follow "Aaaa Bbbb Cccc".

I want to turn this string into a list of strings and an array of string.

To make this possible, in first place I do the following action:

`var list1 = Arrays.stream(input.split(" ")).toList(); System.out.println(list1);`

Then, what appears is `[Aaaa, Bbbb, Cccc]`.

Now it's the turn of the array.

When I print the class of the array, Java says it's has Object as its class (`class [Ljava.lang.Object`).

What can I do get a array of strings instead of Objects?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. (It's not clear how you are creating that array, but probably you need to call `.toArray(String[]::new)` instead of `.toArray()`).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure, if I got you right.
`input.split(" ")` already returns an array of strings. To create a List out of this array, you just have to use

```
Arrays.asList(input.split(" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

An array in Java is internally also an [object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html).

The reason for this output is that the  `toString()` (which is used for output to `println`) method is implemented in the `String` class, but not in the `Array` object. Therefore, the standard `toString()` from the parent `Object` class is used. For similar output, you can use `Arrays.toString()`.

Comment: Also note that `[` refers to arrays and `L` refers to objects (of some class) in type names. So `[Ljava.lang.Object` refers to `Object[]`s.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a String containing words separated by whitespaces like `String str = "Aaaa Bbbb Cccc";`, you can get a String array by using just the split method: `String[] arr = str.split(" ");`. Then you can get a List by using `List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr);`.

However, if I understand your question correctly, you're asking why you're getting an Object array instead of a String array when using `Arrays.stream(str.split(" ")).toArray()`. Here, the reason is that the `Arrays.stream()` method has the following implementations: you can pass an `int[]`, `long[]`, or `double[]` array when the array contains primitive data types. You cannot pass any array of other primitive data types like `char[]` as an argument to `Arrays.stream()`. In your case, your array contains objects of the `String` type; however, the implementation of `Array.stream()` uses a generic data type `T[]` for any non-primitive types. An unbound generic array resolves to the type `Object[]` at runtime and cannot easily be converted to any other type like `String[]`. Hence, you get the output that your array is of type `Object[]` rather than type `String[]`.

So, if you have your variable `str` containing the words and you call `System.out.println(str.split(" "));`, you will get: `[Ljava.lang.String`. But if you call `System.out.println(Arrays.stream(str.split(" ")).toArray());`, you will get: `[Ljava.lang.Object`.

If you want to print the elements of the array in a readable form, you can use the `Arrays.toString()` method: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split(" ")));`. This will print `[Aaaa, Bbbb, Cccc]` to the console.

For the different variants of the `Arrays.stream()` method, see the documentation: [Arrays (Java Platform SE 8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

If you want to better understand arrays of a generic type, see this resource on baeldung.com: [Creating a Generic Array in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-generic-array)